# How to specify partial view of Edit Popup

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with Popup editing.  However, I need to have my own PartialView displayed for editing.

Is there any way to tell the grid what PartialView to display for editing?

If that can't be done, is there a way to wire up the grid so it calls a JavaScript function which would then pop up a custom window that I will populate with a partial view?  It would have to be able to pass the ID of Row that was selected so that the view would edit the correct row.  I know how to create the Window, I just don't know how to call it from the grid and get the Id of the row.

This is the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderSummaryLineItem>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ReportType).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ReferenceId).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(c => c.BorrowerName).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(c => c.PropertyAddress).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(c => c.EstimatedCompletionDate).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ReportPrice).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ExpediteFee).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Discount).Width(75);
        columns.Bound(c => c.TotalPrice).Width(75);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);

    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 600px;" })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model=> model.Id(c=> c.ReferenceId))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "OrderSummary"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "OrderSummary"))
    )
)
```

Update:
I have this partially resolved:  I added a custom Command like this:

```
columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("showDetails");
```

This wires up the "showDetails" JavaScript function.  But I am still not able to pass the current row Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a href='"+Url.Action("EditOrderLineItem","OrderSummary")+"/#=Id#'>Edit</a>");
```